# Phone number format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

I need to check Format Phone Number.

`+33xxxxxxxxx`

`0033xxxxxxxxx`

**EDIT** : `0xxxxxxxxx`

How can I do that with(out) regex ?

Comment: Probably the best library for dealing with phone numbers: http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: @JamesAllardice - This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I don't think it should. It's not a complete answer, it's just a useful reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (/^(?:(?:\+|00)33|0)\d{9}$/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: Oh !!! Great, but If I need to change `33` by `261` or one other value ? What is the code ?

Comment: If you still expect 9 digits after the country code, then just substitute `261` for `33`. And if you want to allow both, use `(?:216|33)` instead of `33`.

Comment: Yes, but if it a random value ?

Comment: If it's random, what are you trying to validate it for? I think you need to go back and think about this, and write down *exactly* what you do and do not want to match.

Comment: All values between 01 and 300

Comment: `if (/^(?:(?:\+|00)33|0)\d{9}$/.test(subject))` : PERFECT

Answer (score 2):

The regex to match it would be this

```
(0033|\+33|0)?\d{9}
```

I use http://regexpal.com/ for quick regex testing

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: `/^((\+|00)\d{2})?\d{9}$/`

This matches each of your given cases (`+YYXXXXXXXXX`, `00YYXXXXXXXXX`, `XXXXXXXXX`).

**Edit:** To match your edit: `/^((\+|00)\d{2}|0)\d{9}$/`

Answer (score 1):

[PhoneFormat.com](http://www.phoneformat.com/) has a javascript library that has some formatting functions that you could easily drop into your project.  It will take whatever number you throw at it and try and convert it to e164 (+ 33252525252), and also format it (+33 2 52 52 52 52)

Answer (score 0):

This is a regex that validates your examples:

```
/(\+|(00)|0)[0-9]{11}/.test(stringToTest)
```

Comment: But it also validates 12345678901.