# validation for phone number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a student form. I need to validate for Phone number. How to validate it using javascript. My form takes even characters for the phone no. Here is the code. Please tel me where do i need to make changes

```
$(function() {
            $("#XISubmit").click(function(){

    var XIStudentPhone = document.forms["XIForm"]["XIStudentPhone"].value;

        if (XIStudentPhone==null || XIStudentPhone=="") { alert("Please Enter Student Phone no"); return false; }
            document.getElementById("XIForm").submit();
            });
```

Comment: It is not easy to validate a phone number since phone numbers can be written in many different ways according to countries and other factors. I think you need to decide one or two allowed formats an use them.

Comment: use regex. refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756510/phone-number-format-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the designation "Student Phone Number", I'm going to assume that internationalisation is *not* an issue here.

In such a case, you can do something like this:

```
<label>Phone number:
    <input type="text" name="XIStudentPhone" pattern="\d{10}" />
    (Please enter numbers only, no spaces or dashes)
</label>
```

This would allow a 10-digit phone number, such as 555-012-3456, and provides the clear instruction to not include any symbols (therefore requiring entry like 5550123456). Depending on what country you're actually in, you may need to adjust it - for example in England you might have 10 or 11 digit phone numbers, so you would have `pattern="\d{10,11}"`.

It is important to note, however, that this makes an *assumption*. It *assumes* that you are only relevant to one particular country, with one particular phone number length. For more general applications, you should probably do something like `pattern="\d{5,14}"` for a wider range of support.

As always, browser-side validation should not be trusted, so make sure you validate on the server too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)  
{  

 var phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
 if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))  
    {  
  return true;  
    }  
  else  
    {  
    alert("message");  
    return false;  
    }
```

}

This code checks the phone number in the format `xxx-xxx-xxxx`

To get other formats refer,
http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function Validate()
        {
            var x = document.XIForm.XIStudentPhone.value;

           if(isNaN(x)||x.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
           {
              alert("Enter numeric value")
              return false; 
           }
           if (x.length>8)
           {
                alert("enter 8 characters");
                return false;
           }
           if (x.charAt(0)!="2")
           {
                alert("it should start with 2 ");
                return false
           }

        }
```

simple function to validate the phone number. you can modify as per your restrictions required.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try the following code

```
  XIStudentPhone = XIStudentPhone.replace(/\D/g,'');
  if(XIStudentPhone.length==0) {
        alert(XIStudentPhone + ' contains empty');
     }
    else if (XIStudentPhone.length == 10) {
        alert(XIStudentPhone + ' contains 10 digits');
     }
     else {
        alert(XIStudentPhone + ' does not contain 10 digits');
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new input type in html5.

```
<input type='tel' pattern='[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}' title='Phone Number (Format: +99(99)9999-9999)'>
```

You can modify the pattern as your wish.

Here is the jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/shyamchandranmec/aLMwq/

and here is a valid phone no. as per the example

```
+99(99)9999-9999
```